# Java: Read input without knowing number of input lines

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

This might be very very basic or may be something I am totally missing. I have started doing some competitive programming on online channels. I have to read comma separated strings and do some manipulations around it but the problem is that I do not know the number of lines of input. Below is the input example

**Input 1**

```
John,Jacob
Lesley,Lewis
Remo,Tina
Brute,Force
```

**Input 2**

```
Hello,World
Java,Coder
........
........
//more input lines
Alex,Raley
Michael,Ryan
```

I am trying to read input and breaking when end of the line is encountered but with no luck. This is what I have been trying

```
//1st method
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

do{
    String relation = in.nextLine();
    //do some manipulation
    System.out.println(relation);

}while(in.nextLine().equals(""));   //reads only first line and breaks

//2nd method
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(in.hasNext()){
    String relation = in.next();
    System.out.println(relation);
    if(relation.equals("")){
        break;
    }
}

//3rd method
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){   //infinite loop
    String relation = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(relation);
    if(relation.equals("")){
        break;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help here.

PS: Please don't judge. I am new to competitive programming though I know how to take user input in java and difference between next() and nextLine().

Comment: You may want to look at the [hasNext](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext.htm) Scanner function in Java, may be what you need!

Comment: No condition. Input is provided by the platform.

Comment: There are numerous articles why you shouldn't use `Scanner` in competitive programming. Instead use `BufferedReader`. In competitive programming they redirect the input to your code from file. So read until `null` is detected in the `while` loop.

Comment: `In competitive programming they redirect the input to your code from file`  the thing I never knew.

Comment: @roger_that it works like `./a.out > output.txt < input.txt` for example

Comment: Understood. Will update the condition accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im not gonna write why you shouldn't use `Scanner`. There are numerous articles why you shouldn't use `Scanner` in competitive programming. Instead use `BufferedReader`.

In competitive programming they redirect the input to your code from file.

It works like `./a.out > output.txt < input.txt` for example.

So read until null is detected in the while loop.

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String s;
        while((s = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

---

For testing through your keyboard, to simulate a `null` from your keyboard:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. It will break out of the `while` loop above.

Comment: This helps a lot.

Comment: @roger_that the accepted answer doesn't really answer your question though . It checks for certain word to break the loop. But in your question you said you don't know the condition or no. of lines of input to take.

Comment: Oh yeah. The actual idea i got was from your first comment.

Answer (score 2):

It should be fairly easy. Try

```
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    String relation = in.nextLine();
    if("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(relation))break;
    //do some manipulation
    System.out.println(relation);    
}
```

The method `Scanner#hasNextLine` simply checks if there is a next line in the input, doesn't really advance the scanner. On the other hand, `Scanner#nextLine` reads the input as well as advances the scanner.

**Update** you might want to put some condition to exit the loop. E.g. the above snippet stops reading more input after it encounters a string "exit".

Comment: Have tried this in eclipse but the loop doesn't terminates and keeps waiting for the input

Comment: @roger_that, you need to put a condition on when to stop. Let me edit my answer

Comment: @roger_that you have to send a signal like passing null through keyboard to say there is no input to give. press `ctrl+d` in mac. I dont know about windows though

Comment: Understood. The input is redirected through a file in competitive programming. I think I need to have some condition around that.

Comment: for a challange with various length's reading the csv data from a file would also be favourable. if you read from a file hasNextLine() is condition enough for exiting just let your Scanner read from a new File("data.csv")

Answer (score 0):

All your methods can be improved.

But let's consider your second method of while loop.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s;

    while(in.hasNext()){
        s=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(s);
       
    }
```

In the same way, you can change each of your codes.
Also you can use `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` to buffer your input then check for `in.readLine()) != null`

Answer (score -1):

Other than the above two methods (Buffered Reader method & Scanner method), I have another method for solving this issue. Have a look at the following code, you can catch `NoSuchElementException` to solve this issue , though I didn't recommended this as Exception handling is a costly process .

Out of all the methods, the Buffered should only be used during Competitive Coding as it has the least Complexity.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        try   
        {
            while(true)
             String    a=sc.next();
            System.out.print(a);

        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException  k)
        {
        }


    }
}
```